# Google App Script UrlFetchApp.fetch API Key Header: getting 401 error

Tags: google-apps-script, api-key, http-status-code-401, urlfetch, unauthorized

I have an Infobip test account and I am trying to use send a message to a user using their API. As an authorization type, I am using the API Key Header. I believe I don't know where to place this key on the code. I am trying to use the key on the header but I am always getting the error 401. I know that I am not using the correct payload parameters according to the documentation but anyway, I believe this is not the reason to generate this error.

```
function myFunction_infobip() {
 
  var url = "https://*base URL given*.api.infobip.com/omni/1/advanced";
  var authHeader = '';
  var payload = JSON.stringify({
  "scenarioKey":"AD9E01A5DC7BEE2C2B828D208182A611",
  "whatsApp":{"text":"test."},});
 
  var headers = {
        "Authorization": "App <API key given>",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"};
 
  var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "headers": headers,
    "payload": payload
  };
 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log("response: "+response);
}
```

I would be very grateful for any advice/clue here!

Comment: I'm not sure, but based on [the official docs](https://www.infobip.com/docs/essentials/api-authentication#api-key-header), I'd say you have to append the string `App` before the API key on the Authorization header, like `"Authorization": "App " + API_KEY`. Can you check if that solves your issue? In that case, I would consider posting this as an answer.

Comment: Hi @Iamblichus, thanks a lot for your comment. I forgot to place in the code above the "App" part but I was running the code with it already when I got this error. But glad that you noticed, I have already edited the code here. I have no idea what could be generating this error. Should I edit the manifest file? I'm lost here

Comment: `I believe this is not the reason to generate this error.` Why not? Everything else seems to be in order. I would guess the server is not allowing access to the resource because you don't have access to the requested resource

Comment: @TheMaster I thought an error due to that would give a "bad request" error and not an "unauthorized" one but I will give a try to that and see if it is that

Comment: Bad request would be thrown if there are syntax errors in your payload. But if the resources you're requesting are not manually accessible by you in the first place, I believe 401 is appropriate. Furthermore, servers don't need to be complaint with all the http status codes

Comment: @TheMaster `Bad request would be thrown if there are syntax errors in your` -> exactly, what was the case here, they were with the wrong syntax. I changed the parameters for the correct syntax and I still got the 401 error as I thought so. However, I was already able to get it. I placed the URL inside the payroll and now it is working perfectly. I will post the solution there. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user14491665 Add the answer in the answer box below and not in the question.

Answer (score 1):

*Answer from OP moved from question:*

---

For those with the same problem, after a lot of tries, I found the solution. I just added the URL inside the payload also and it works perfectly now:

```
function myFunction_infobip() {
 
  var url = "https://*base URL given*.api.infobip.com/omni/1/advanced";
  var authHeader = '';
  var payload = JSON.stringify({
  "url": "https://*base URL given*.api.infobip.com/omni/1/advanced",
  "scenarioKey":"AD9E01A5DC7BEE2C2B828D208182A611",
  "WhatsApp":<insert here the parameters>);
 
  var headers = {
        "Authorization": "App <API key given>",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"};
 
  var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "headers": headers,
    "payload": payload
  };
 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log("response: "+response);
}
```